# HTTPInterceptor in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

We have APIs which returns errors inside the reponse XMLs instead of rejecting them and sending error responses. 
So I have the following code to handle them,

```
                $http({
                    url: apiURL,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: req,
                    headers: oHeaders,
                    dataType: "xml",
                })
                .success(function(data,status) {
                    console.log('success!!!!!');
                    deff.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(data,status) {
                    console.log('This is what I want to see!!!!!');
                    deff.reject(data);
                });


myApp.factory('customHttpInterceptor', ['$q', function ($q) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            var parsed;
            if (response.config.dataType == 'xml'){
                parsed = $.xml2json(response.data);
                if (parsed) {
                    angular.forEach(parsed, function(v, k) {
                        if (k == 'status') { 
                            if (v.APIErrors) {
                                return $q.reject(response);
                            }     
                        }                          
                    });                     
                }
                console.log(parsed);
            }   
            return response;
        }, function (errResponse) {
            // do something on error
            console.log('Error section in interceptor');
            return $q.reject(errResponse);
        });
    };
}]);
```

What I expected to get from is that when an error is identified within the interceptor it will reject the promise and the control would get into the error section of the $http and log the "This is what I want to see!!!!!" message. But instead is show the "success!!!!!" message.

Is this the way it works or am I doing something wrong?

Ish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several things that seem wrong here :

**Returning a result in `forEach`**

```
angular.forEach(parsed, function(v, k) {
  if (k == 'status') {
    if (v.APIErrors) {
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  }
});
```

You probably wrote this because you're used to put `return` statements inside for loops. This does not work here, because you're returning from inside a function body. There is ***never*** any reason to return something in a `forEach` body function: this value is not going to be used by anything.

**Angular Interceptor API**

Maybe you just didn't show it in your code, but you have to register your interceptor.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('customHttpInterceptor');
```

What's more, your interceptor does not have the correct form : in your case, it should be a object with a `response` method that returns a promise of a response from a response.

Comment: Thanks. The problem indeed was returning inside the forEach.